# Moving list element from one unordered list to another with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have looked at a few of the other answers to this question, but I have still not been able to get it done correctly.  I have two unordered lists.  One is dynamically created from a database table.  The other is just a static table that begins empty.  Each list contains, or will contain, list elements with nested anchor and awesome-font icon elements.  My goal is to be able to, upon clicking the icon, transfer the list element from one list to the other, while changing the icon from a plus to minus sign.  So far, I can successfully transfer items from the dynamic list to the static one, and I can change the icons, but I can not figure out how to transfer them back to the original list.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="row" id="constructTable">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Choose your Columns:</h1>
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" id="heading1" role="tab">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1" class="collapsed"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Candidate Data</span></a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading1" aria-expanded="false" style="height:0px;">
                        <ul class="list-group choose" id="candidate">
                            <li class="list-group-item" id="candidate0">
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-plus"></i>
                                </a>
                                <span style="font-size: 14px; margin-left:5px;">First Name</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item" id="candidate1">
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                                    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-plus"></i>
                                </a>
                                <span style="font-size: 14px; margin-left:5px;">Last Name</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $counter = 2; ?>
            <?php foreach ($mergedTests as $test): ?>
                <?php $count=0 ?>
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" style="margin-top:-10px;">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" id="heading<?php echo $counter; ?>" role="tab">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $counter; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="collapsed">
                                <span style="font-size: 16px;"><?php if( ! $test->example ): ?><?php echo $test->example;  ?> Data<?php else: ?><?php echo $test->example; ?> Data<?php endif; ?></span>
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php $label = explode(",", $test->subtestLabel); ?>
                    <div id="collapse<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo $counter; ?>" aria-expanded="false" style="height:0px;">
                        <ul class="list-group" id="<?php echo $test->subTestAbbreviation; ?>">
                            <?php if ( ! $test->testMakerTestId) : ?>
                                <?php foreach($label as $category): ?>
                                    <li class="list-group-item" id="<?php echo $test->example; ?><?php echo $count; ?>" >
                                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                                            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-plus"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <span  style="font-size: 14px; margin-left:5px;"><?php echo $test->example; ?> <?php echo $category; ?></span>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php $count++; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <li class="list-group-item" id="<?php echo $test->subTestAbbreviation; ?>0">
                                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                                        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-plus"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <span style="font-size: 14px; margin-left:5px;"><?php echo $test->example; ?> Raw Score</span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="list-group-item" id="<?php echo $test->subTestAbbreviation; ?>1">
                                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                                        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-plus"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <span style="font-size: 14px; margin-left:5px;"><?php echo $test->example; ?> Percentile</span>
                                </li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php $counter++; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Arrange Your Columns:</h1>
            <ul class="list-group ui-sortable" id="selectedColumns">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JQuery attempt so far:

```
$('li a').click(function(){
    var parentId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $(this).find($(".fa")).removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
    $("#selectedColumns").append($("#" + parentId));
});

//  Move selection from Arrange Your Columns back to Choose Your Columns
$('ul#selectedColumns').click(function(){
    var parentId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    console.log(parentId);
    transferId = parentId.slice(0, -1);
    $("#" + parentId).find($(".fa")).removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
    $("#" + transferId).append($("#" + parentId));
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you will use $("li a") as your click selector, this will bind this event to all anchor tags inside a list element. Since you have 2 lists I dont think you would want that. I suppose

Comment: I have tried changing the li in that selector to the class ".choose" on the first unordered list, but it has not had any affect.

Comment: Ok trying to figure out what you are trying to do here. I think you have multiple source lists coming from database right?

Comment: Yes, the first ul has one static drop down list, and then creates several other drop down lists from a database query that is done in my controller.  Once the list element has moved to the selectedColumns ul, when it is clicked again, I want it to return to the correct dropdown list in the first column.  I'm probably making it sound more confusing than it is.

Comment: Check my answer, I would do it like this but since I don't have the codes you have to do the testing. but this may give you an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here you may need to use names for these lists, the target is selectedColumns, and the source is unordered lists has some database generated id. I will put a class name source-list to your datbase generated lists.

We can use this class name as a common selector of source lists and since the dom will change via user interaction we should use .on instead of .click binding.

First we send a clone of the selected item to selectedColumns and hide the original one so we wont have to find exact place of the element to roll back;

```
$(".source-list").on("li a","click", function(e) {
    // get id of element for further reference
    var itemId = $(this).attr("id");

    // clone the item to a variable
    var cloneItem = $(this).parent().clone();
    // change the appearence of cloned item
    cloneItem.find($(".fa")).removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
    // append cloned item to selectedColumns
    cloneItem.data("id", itemId).removeAttr('id').appendTo("#selectedColumns");
    // hide the original item
    $(this).hide();
});

$("#selectedColumns").on("li a","click", function(e) {
    var itemId = $(this).data("id");
    $(this).remove();
    $(itemId).show();
});
```

Since this code has alot of errors / typos, i have created a fiddle for this,

https://jsfiddle.net/wxsnagr9/7/

Comment: I've tried this a couple of different ways, and so far it hasn't worked.  I like the idea though.

Comment: No errors.  Just when I click on the first list item, nothing happens

Comment: I may have some typos, http://api.jquery.com/on/ here it says it should be .on("click", "li a", function(e) { ....

Comment: That did actually help, but now all that is moved is the icon.  The words still stay in both lists.

Comment: well it seems there is more then one error in my code. preparing a fiddle.

Comment: I appreciate the time you are spending on this with me.  Thanks!

Comment: Mind the class names I have used to reference the source lists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88223/discussion-between-azadrum-and-jldavis76).

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like what you have should be fine for the most part, you should just fix the selectors (also, using event delegation will save you from needing to bind data/recheck parent locations):

```
$('#candidate').click('li a', function(){
    $(this).find(".fa").removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
    $(this).parent().appendTo($("#selectedColumns"));
});


$('#selectedColumns').click('li a', function(){
    $(this).find(".fa").addClass('fa-plus').removeClass('fa-minus');
    $(this).parent().appendTo($("#candidate"));
});
```